# Some way to load geoJson faster in google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a big geojson file for a layer in my project, it has over 16000 lines in it. For people with a normal pc, it will take for about 10 to 20 seconds to load, and on some computers it won't even load because the browser reports it is crashing. Is there any way to load it asynchronously, so the webpage isn't stuck while loading? And is there any way to make this loading more efficient?

I currently load it using the default way, `.loadGeoJson(path)`

Comment: How are you loading it now?

Comment: the default way `map.data.loadGeoJson(source)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we decided to go with webworkers, which makes it much faster, still lagging.